# Forcing uninitialised declaration of member with a default constructor

Tags: c++

I discovered this phenomenon today, where a member is unnecessarily constructed twice:

```
#include <iostream>

class Member {
public:
    Member() {
        std::cout << "Created member (default)" << std::endl;
    }

    Member(int i) {
        std::cout << "Created member: " << i << std::endl;
    }
};

class Object {
    Member member;

public:
    Object() {
        member = 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    Object o;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to declare the member ***uninitialised*** - instead of using the default constructor - hence forcing you to use the initialiser lists in the constructor?

In Java, if you define a member like so: `Member i;` and you don't initialise it in every constructor, you'll get an error saying the field may be uninitialised, when trying to use it.

If I remove the default constructor from the `Member` class, I get the behaviour I want - the compiler forces you to use an initialiser list for every constructor - but I want this to happen in general, to stop me from forgetting to use this form instead (when a default constructor is available).

---

Essentially, I wanted protection against mistakenly using the default constructor, but it looks like this doesn't exist...

Even when marking the constructor with the `explicit` keyword, `Member member` still generates a member - that's immediately discarded when it's reassigned in the constructor. This itself seems inconsistent as well...

My main problem is the inconsistency. You can declare an uninitialised member if it has no default constructor; this is actually useful; you don't need to feed an initial redundant declaration, but simply initialise at the constructor (and break if not initialised). This functionality is completely missing for classes with a default constructor.

---

A related example is:

```
std::string s;
s = "foo";
```

You could simply do: `std::string s = "foo";` instead, however if `"foo"` is actually multiple lines - as opposed to a single expression - we get non-atomic initialisation.

```
std::string s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) s += i;
```

This initialisation could easily end up in a torn write.

If you split it up, like so, it's assigned nearly atomically, however you still have the default value used as a placeholder:

```
std::string member;
// ...
std::string s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) s += i;
member = s;
```

In this code, you could actually simply move the `member` variable down after `s` is fully constructed; however, in a class, this isn't possible, as **a member with a default constructor must be initialised at decleration** - despite members without a default constructor not being restricted in the same way.

In the above case, the redundant use of `std::string`'s default constructor is relatively inexpensive, but that wouldn't hold for all situations.

---

I don't want the default constructor gone, I just want an option to leave the member uninitialised until the constructor - the same way I can with types with no default constructor. To me, it seems like such a simple feature and I'm puzzled by why it's not supported/

It seems that this would have *naturally* been implemented (whenever uninitialised declaration of types with no default constructor was) if not for bracketless instantiation of a class being supported, which presumptuously instantiates classes - even when you want them left uninitialised, like my situation.

---

EDIT: Running into this problem again

In java you can do this

```java
int x; // UNINITIALISED
if (condition){
   x = 1; // init x;
}
else return;
use(x); // INITIALISED
```

In c++ this is not possible???
It initialises with the default constructor, but this isn't necessary - its wasteful.
**- note: you can not use the uninitialised variable**.
As you can see, because I'm using `x` outside of the loop, it has to get declared there, at which point it's - unnecessarily - initialised.
Another scenario where `int x = delete` would be useful. It would break no code, and only cause a compile-time error when trying to use the uninitialised x.
**There's no uninitialised memory or undeterministic state**, it's simply a compile-time thing - that Java has been able to implement well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215865/discussion-on-question-by-tobi-akinyemi-forcing-uninitialised-declaration-of-mem).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62647060/how-can-i-conditionally-instantiate-an-object related question

Answer (score 7):

It's important to remember that C++ is not Java. In C++, variables are *objects*, not references to objects. When you create an object in C++, you have *created an object*. Calling a default constructor to create an object is *just as valid* as calling any other constructor. In C++, once you enter the body of a class's constructor, all of its member subobjects are fully-formed objects (at least, as far as the language is concerned).

If there is some type which has a default constructor, that means that it is 100% OK for you to use that default constructor to create an instance of that type. Such an object is not "uninitialized"; it is initialized via its default constructor.

In short, it is *wrong* for you to consider a default constructed object "uninitialized" or otherwise invalid. Not unless that default constructor explicitly leaves the object in a non-functional state.

> I don't want the default constructor gone, I just want an option to leave the member uninitialised until the constructor - the same way I can with types with no default constructor.

Again, C++ is not Java. The term "uninitialized" in C++ means something completely different than when you're dealing with Java.

Java declares references, C++ declares *objects* (and references, but they have to be bound immediately). If an object is "uninitialized", it is *still an object* in C++. The object has undefined values, and thus you are limited in how you may access it. But it is still a complete and total object as far as C++'s object model is concerned. You can't construct it later (not without placement-new).

In Java, to leave a variable uninitialized means that there is no object; it's a null reference. C++ has no equivalent language concept, not unless the member in question is a pointer to an object rather than the object itself. Which is a pretty heavy-weight operation.

In any case, in C++, the author of a class has the right to restrict how that class works. This includes how it gets initialized. If the author of a class wants to ensure that certain values in that object are always initialized, then they get to do that and there is *nothing* you can do to stop it.

Generally speaking, you should avoid trying to do what you're doing. If however there is some type that you must initialize outside of the constructor member initializer list, and you don't want to call its default constructor (or it doesn't have one), then you can use `std::optional<T>`, where `T` is the type in question. `optional` is what it sounds like: an object that may or may not hold a `T`. Its default constructor starts without a `T`, but you can create a new `T` with `optional::emplace`. And you can access the `T` with pointer syntax like `->` or `*`. But it never heap-allocates the `T`, so you don't have that overhead.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215866/discussion-on-answer-by-nicol-bolas-forcing-uninitialised-declaration-of-member).

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to provide a simple generic wrapper that prevents default construction, while allowing for all other use cases.  It needn't be much; a naïve approach like this, for example, should do the task well enough.<sup>1</sup>

```
#include <utility> // std::forward()

template<typename T>
class NoDefaultConstruct {
    T data;

// All member functions are declared constexpr to preserve T's constexpr-ness, if applicable.
public:
    // Prevents NoDefaultConstruct<T> from being default-constructed.
    // Doesn't actually prevent T itself from being default-constructed, but renders T's
    //  default constructor inaccessible.
    constexpr NoDefaultConstruct() = delete;

    // Provides pass-through access to ALL of T's constructors, using perfect forwarding.
    // The deleted constructor above hides pass-through access to T's default constructor.
    template<typename... Ts>
    constexpr NoDefaultConstruct(Ts&&... ts) : data{std::forward<Ts>(ts)...} {}

    // Allow NoDefaultConstruct<T> to be implicitly converted to a reference to T, allowing
    //  it to be used as a T& in most constructs that want a T&.  Preserves const-ness.
    constexpr operator T&()       { return data; }
    constexpr operator T&() const { return data; }
};
```

---

If we then use this in `Object`...

```
class Object {
    //Member member;
    NoDefaultConstruct<Member> member;

public:
    // Error: Calls deleted function.
    //Object() {
    //    member = 1;
    //}

    Object() : member(1) {}
};
```

...We are now required to explicitly initialise `member` in the initialiser list, due to the original `Object` default constructor's implicit call to `decltype(member)()` being sent on a shady detour through `NoDefaultConstruct`ville's `delete`d back alleys.

---

<sup>1: Note that while `NoDefaultConstruct<T>` will behave more-or-less identically to `T` in most cases, there are exceptions.  The most noticeable is during template argument deduction, along with anywhere else that template argument deduction rules are used.</sup>

Comment: Tbh I found this one harder to follow originally than the other variation - probably because I'm new to C++

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi: Just to let you know, if you use this sort of thing heavily and another C++ developer looks at your code, they will have nothing nice to say.  I thought about writing this sort of wrapper in my answer as well, but decided not to because it is basically impractical for C++ code which will be maintained.  Same goes for the other answer with a similar wrapper solution.

Comment: The question was asking whether C++ supported this natively.

Comment: @Justin Does this still support the use of the default constructor, if I want to *intentionally* call it?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have endless not nice things to say to the developers who worked on my current codebase....that being said, i wasn't around when they had to make the choices they did. Sometimes you have to do things you don't like. For what its worth, i upvoted your answer before providing one.

Comment: Unfortunately, @TobiAkinyemi, using something like this disables usage of the wrapped type's default constructor.  It technically _supplies_ access to `T`'s default constructor through the template constructor... but it's a moot point because if you attempt to call it, the deleted constructor will be chosen instead during overload resolution (due to non-template functions having higher priority than template specialisations when both are otherwise identical).

Comment: (There _are_ ways to work around that, but at that point it'd be better to look into using a style guide enforcing tool or linter, with a custom style rule that all constructors must have member initialisation lists.  @JohnZwinck is correct, heavy usage of behaviour-altering wrappers both makes things more convoluted and has the potential to introduce hidden gotchas (one of which has been edited into my answer, as a footnote).  It can be useful in certain cases, though.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature in any mainstream C++ compiler.  How do I know?  Because it would break (or warn about) basically every existing C++ library.  What you're asking for doesn't exist, but moreover cannot exist in a compiler which compiles C++.

Comment: It wouldn't break any code, the uninitialised declaration could simply be opt-in. I.e. something like `Member member = delete`

Comment: Oh I see.  Now you are asking for a new feature to be added to the C++ language.  You could write a proposal for the appropriate C++ working group.  But to be honest I don't think this one will gain much support.  It's always a bit tricky moving from one language to another, one tends to expect all one's favourite idioms will be supported in the new language....

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi I dont see how this address your question.  You stated you dont have access to the class in question. If you have access to the class to say `member member = delete` you have access to delete the default constructor.

Comment: @Taekahn What do you mean? I have access to `Object` (which is there the uninitialised declaration would occur) - not `Member`

Comment: I still think your best bet is to inherit from the class to essentially delete the default constructor, unless that is also not an option. You could probably write it out to be a template and apply it to all the classes you want.

Comment: I don't want the default constructor gone, I just want an option to leave the member uninitialised until the constructor - the same way I can with types with no default constructor. To me, it seems like such a simple feature and I'm puzzled why it wasn't implemented.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi Not 100% sure it answers your question, but i added an answer that shows what i was talking about.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi When you say you want to leave the member uninitialised, is it fair to say you want this for performance reasons?  Have you analysed the generated code to see if there is actually a performance issue after the optimiser has a go at it?  I suspect the problem is an imagined one, if it's about performance.

Comment: Not really a performance thing, rather correctness. Doesn't it make sense to assign a member once, instead of twice?

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi: In C++ it can be correct and also optimal to default construct something and then assign or overwrite (at least part of) it.  It is safer, too, because as soon as the body of your constructor (after the initialisation list) is entered, you know all members are valid objects, not some partial/unusable ones.

Comment: @JohnZwinck It'd be just as safe; members would still be initialised when entering the constructor - just as they would in the non-default example - however, you'd just be forced to use the initialiser list on the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

So based on the discussion we've had in the comments, it *sounds* like something this might fit the bill of what you're looking for?
As has been mentioned the exact thing you're looking for in C++ doesn't exist, but there are language features to get you pretty close i think.

```
template <typename T>
struct must_init
{
    using type = std::remove_cvref_t<T>;
    type t;
    must_init(type&& t) : t{std::move(t)} {}
};
```

If you wrap a class in this, you won't be able to compile  without assigning to it.
i.e.

```
class A
{
    must_init<std::string> s;
};
```

will give you a compiler error saying s has to be initialized, whereas if you define it like

```
class A
{
    A() : s{""} {}
    must_init<std::string> s;
};
```

this will compile.
You can call the default constructor like so

```
class A
{
    A() : s{{}} {}
    must_init<std::string> s;
};
```

godbolt. https://godbolt.org/z/e_nsRQ

Comment: This is the closest thing to what I wanted so far

Comment: What's up with the double brackets `s{""}{}`

Comment: We appear to both have supplied variants of the same idea within seconds of each other. ;P

Comment: The second set of braces are the constructor's body, @TobiAkinyemi, there's just no space between it and `s`'s initialiser.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi Sorry, its a habit. {} is the "preferred" way to initialize in modern c++. `()` works as well for the first braces. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/uniform-initialization-in-c/

Comment: @Taekahn its fine, I thought the double brackets were an artifact of how `must_init` worked, but its just the method body

Comment: @JustinTime-ReinstateMonica Yes, indeed. Just looked at yours. If not for you i probably wouldn't have noticed that i used move instead of (correctly) forward.  :)

Comment: Does this still allow me to *intentionally* call the default constructor? i.e. `A() : s() {}`

Comment: Mine actually doesn't, either, @Taekahn, thanks to overload resolution.  The deleted constructor has higher priority than the template constructor when you supply an empty parameter list.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi Sorry, it was _super_ late my time when i posted all this. Yes mine does in fact allow you to call the default constructor, you have to do so explicitly like `{}`. I've updated my answer to include this as well as make the template a little harder to misuse.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too as I used to develop in Java as my first language and I'm switching to C++ for personal reasons *(I needed lower access level)*.

In my particular case, I have a `sf::Thread` object that I wanted to declare inside a class, **without initializing it**. As this is part of SFML, I cannot change its implementation.

In a different section of the project, I want to actually create the thread and start it.

I was hitting compilation issues due to `sf::Thread` not being instantiated, because when you declare it as a member of a class the constructor is automatically called.

After some research, I found about [Smart Pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), for example `std::unique_ptr`. This **pointer** owns and manages another object. I found it useful for what I wanted to accomplish, with the drawback that you have to deal with a pointer *(So you should free it once you're done with it)*:

```
// Somewhere (In your case in your main function, in my case it was a member of another class)
std::unique_ptr<sf::Thread> thread_background;

// In the calling method
void start_thread_background(){
    thread_background.reset(new sf::Thread(/*sf::Thread arguments*/));
    thread_background->launch(); // You must call methods with -> because it's a pointer now
}
```

Comment: Also started in Java and switched for the same reason

Comment: Using heap allocation, smart pointers, wrappers, etc. as a way to delay construction is a workaround that works and some projects use, but it does not solve the issue since they do not force you to initialize the member in the initializer list (or somewhere).

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `optional<sf::Thread>` if it is imperative that you delay initialization of the object. You'll avoid unnecessary heap allocation, at the cost of some bloat in the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have run up against two intentional design decisions of C++ which prevent you from creating the workflow check you want (you're warned against initializing a member in a constructor body when you could have used its initializer list) using language features alone.

One, the designers of C++ decided to make it so there is no such thing as an uninitialized object. This is why constructors can do only two things - make a functional object, or throw an exception. Uninitialized types can cause headaches (and in C++ uninitialized integers often do) so the designers eliminated that state from objects entirely when they wrote the language spec.

Two, the designers also decided that all objects should have an automatically generated default constructor, unless certain conditions are met. (For example, the presence of a user-written default constructor, user deletion of the default constructor with the =delete syntax, or a member which itself cannot be default initialized, such as a reference type.)

You can't get what you want using language features alone, so you can either get what you want using extensions such as a linter, or you can change what you want.

I'd recommend the latter, i.e. adapting to the typical C++ way of doing things. It will cause you less friction when using the language. Specifically I'd recommend embracing the deletion of default constructors when you really want to express "this object cannot be constructed without additional information," and in all other cases, just acquiring the habit of initializing class members in constructor initializer lists. You want to follow best practice by doing this, but unfortunately there's no straightforward way to build yourself a guardrail, you just have to pay attention and enforce the rule on yourself.

There may be linters which you can get to generate warnings when a member is initialized in the constructor body when it could have been initialized in the initializer list, but I'm not personally aware of any.