# Why doesn't C++ support smart analysis of uninitialised variables?

Tags: java, c++

Here's a use case Java covers:

```java
int x; // UNINITIALISED
if (condition){
   x = 0; // init x;
}
else return;
use(x); // INITIALISED
```

Note:

- There is at no point uninitialized memory (for x)
- There is no non-deterministic state
- You can not use an uninitialised variable
- The variable is truly uninitialized, not `null` or `0` - however this doesn't leak into the run-time; I presume the compiler restructures the code, *at compile time* so `x` is initialised at deceleration *only when necessary*. `x` may be uninitialised in the code, however at runtime it's guaranteed to be initialised (which is why there's an error when you try to use it before initialisation).

---

From what I've seen/heard, C++ does not support this and will always run a default constructor - if available - even when it's unnecessary.

Interestingly, when a default constructor is unavailable, you actually get the same behaviour with uninitialized variables in Java. So, it's clearly possible for the C++ compiler to handle this behaviour (because it *is* with classes with no default constructor). So, why is it not supported fully?

I think syntax like `int x = delete` or `[[no-default]] int x` for this (as to not break any existing code) would be quite intuitive.

---

Please note, there's a difference between `int x` and `int x = 0` - in Java.
Contrary to `@akuzminykh`s comment, it's *not* "initialised to 0" - I don't know why people are upvoting it

In the example, if you comment out the `init x`, you get an error - this will not happen in C++ - you will get undefined behaviour, because you're using uninitialised memory.

```java
int x; // UNINITIALISED
if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
//    x = 0; // init x;
} else return;
use(x); // ERROR: Variable 'x' might not have been initialized
```

---

I understand Java uses pointers, that is irrelevant to the essence of this question. This has nothing to do with the run-time, it's compile-time analysis.

---

Another scenario:

```
bool valid = false;
Type lastValid; // unnecessary default initialisation (only in C++)
for (auto object : objects)
    try {
        lastValid = process(object);
        valid = true;
    } catch (std::invalid_argument) {}
if (valid) use(lastValid);
```

---

Another Scenario: [Forcing uninitialised declaration of member with a default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354194/forcing-uninitialised-declaration-of-member-with-a-default-constructor)

---

More info: someone used this code in an example comparison between Java and C++

> Example.java

```
Type x; // Reserve stack space for a pointer.
```

> Example.cpp

```
Type x; // Reserve stack space for the object (and initialize it).
```

One mistake everyone seems to be making is like the comment above `// Reserve stack space for a pointer`, this is *not* what happens in Java.

The variable doesn't exist at that point during run-time. There's no allocation, no reservation, simply no unnecessary computation. The compiler is smart enough to do this. Again, this is not to do with the run-time; comparisons between the differences of java and c++ are misleading.

The reason you get an error when trying to use the uninitialised variable, is because the variable literally does not exist (at that point) during run-time (as it wasn't initialised). This is done using analysis of the code tree

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216395/discussion-on-question-by-tobi-akinyemi-why-doesnt-c-support-smart-analysis-o).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question has lost clarity via the edits that reply to comments. In addition, the focus of those edits have made the question look more like an attempt to prove a point (that Java is superior) than an attempt to gain understanding (of C++). A rewrite seems to be in order, one that presents the scenario in less argumentative terms and that clearly specifies what exactly the author is looking for. The tips provided in [ask] might be useful.

Comment: @JaMiT I wasn't arguing that Java is better - nor do I think it is. I was simply addressing this feature missing in the CPP compiler, that Java has. The majority of the people who found this question - including yourself - jumped to the conclusion that I was talking about memory initialisation at run-time; despite me trying my hardest to make it clear. Yes, the question has been edited many times, but these were for *clarification*. The original question and this question are talking about the exact same thing - only I've elaborated, by addressing all of the misconceptions

Answer (score 5):

Java is a very different language to C++.

- In Java:

  Variables without an explicit initialiser are initialised to a default value.

  Variables of class types do not hold the memory of the object in-place. Rather, a variable is a pointer/reference to an object stored in the heap (called free store in C++). The closest thing comparable to Java object variable in C++ is `std::shared_ptr`. It's not an exact equivalent, since (besides the different lifetime management strategy) indirection through a Java variable is implicit (like C++ reference) while indirection through a  C++ shared pointer is explicit through the use of indirection operator.

  The indirection makes it possible for Java variable to be null. A null variable doesn't point to any object. The default value for an object variable is null.

  In case of primitive types such as `int`, the variable is not a pointer. The default value for integer is 0.
- In C++:

  Variables are not implicitly references or pointers. A pointer to a class is a different type from that class.

  A variable that is not a reference nor a pointer does not involve indirection. It doesn't point to an object elsewhere and because there is no pointer, there is no null. If you create such variable, then an object of that type is created.

  When given no initialiser, the way a variable is initialised depends on the type as well as the storage class of the variable. For example, fundamental types such as pointers and integers, as well as trivially default constructible classes are left with an indeterminate value unless they have static storage class. Construction of such object requires no instructions to be executed by the CPU. This is fast, but difficult and potentially dangerous because there is no way to distinguish whether a value is indeterminate or well defined.

---

To answer the question "why": Because that is the way the language was designed.

Using indirection (which Java does) is slower than not using indirection. Using heap allocation (which Java does) is slower than allocating in-place. Always initialising value to something such as integer to 0 (which Java does) is (marginally) slower than not initialising when that value would later always be over-written. Runtime performance is often a reason behind design choices that make a language more complex or harder to use. Runtime performance is the main reason why most people use C++.

Comment: I dont think you understand the question. This is code analysis done by the compiler - nothing to do with the run-time / pointer usage.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi You stated `C++ does not support this and will always run a default constructor`. This explains why that is the case (because the object is always created; the variable is not a pointer). You showed an example where you can test whether a Java variable points to an object. This explains why that is possible. You asked why C++ is different from Java. This explains why that is the case (the choices allow a faster language). It is not possible to meaningfully compare two languages before establishing how those languages differ from one another.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi If the compiler notices that you read an uninitialized variable it'll warn you about that. Are you asking _why_ it's possible to create variables in an uninitialized state or are you asking _why_ the compiler gives a warning if you read from an uninitialized variable?

Comment: @TedLyngmo my point is, that warning could be turned into an error - which is preferable - by having `int x = delete`, which signifies "don't use default initialiser"

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi The warning can be turned into an error with `-Werror` or similar.

Comment: It's not as deterministic as Java's *concrete* implementation - thus is not equivalent

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi Is `-Werror` not as deterministic or do you mean that reading uninitialized variables isn't always spotted by the compiler?

Comment: Default initialisers might be what you want, in this case this error would be a false negative... There's no way around it other than having some explicit way of expressing "don't default initialise".

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi You lost me there. I don't understand that answer.

Comment: In java, because it doesn't have default constructors, this explicit marking is not necessary

Comment: @TedLyngmo Some classes, unlike int, may provide a meaningful default initialisation. In this case, the compiler would falsely error (with your suggestion) saying "usage of uninitialised variable".

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi Like a `std::string`? I don't see any complaints from g++, clang++ or MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/TcTRym

Comment: @TedLyngmo What are you demonstrating with that code snippet?

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi A class with a default constructor that initializes its members. It doesn't give a false error when read.

Comment: @TedLyngmo So what you're saying is `std::string` is whitelisted by the compiler? That does not solve the general case

Comment: Or is it that the `int` class is black-listed - which is even worse coverage

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi There cannot be an uninitialised variable of non-primitive (i.e. `class` or `struct`) type in C++. It's just not possible - object must be created when it's defined, no going around that. No sane compiler would issue a warning about unitialized variable of class type, because it's never uninitialized. Now whether that default constructor initializes class members correctly or not, that's a different matter.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi No, `std::string` is not special. It just has a default constructor that initializes the members with  meaningful values.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen @eerorika `The variable is truly uninitialized, not null or 0 - however this doesn't leak into the run-time; I presume the compiler restructures the code, at compile time so x is initialised at deceleration only when necessary. x may be uninitialised in the code, however at runtime it's guaranteed to be initialised (which is why there's an error when you try to use it before initialisation)`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen You can have uninitialized variables of `class` or `struct` type. For example `X x;` where `struct X {int i;};`  `x`is not initialized.

Comment: @doug `x` is initialized with default constructor (implicitly generated by compiler), `x.i` is not initialized.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen You are correct. the implicit default constructor for a trivial class does vacuous initialization.That is nothing at all. I find it hard to consider that any kind of "initialization" in the usual meaning of the word but, of course, c++ standard language is not so constrained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) for this. Example:

```cpp
std::optional<Type> x;
if (condition) {
   x.emplace(); // default construct Type
}
else return;

use(x.value()); // will throw std::bad_optional_access if x is not actually initialized
```

Comment: The `int` example specifically requires nothing like `std::optional` as integral types are not default initialized.

Comment: This is not equivalent, in the java example, `x` is *always* initialised when `use` is called

Comment: @＿Static＿assert sure but you have no checking as to whether it's initialized, just UB.

Comment: @Charles there is no way the `if` body gets executed and the variable is left initialized. If it's not executed, then the function returns and again there is no way the uninitialized variable is used.

Comment: @＿Static＿assert exactly.

Comment: Fair enough. Code could probably be reorganized as well to entirely avoid the use of `std::optional` in cases where it's not an `int` (like moving the `use()` and variable declaration in the `if` block).

Answer (score 0):

For built-in types, C++ does allow uninitialized variables, so your code will [compile fine in C++ too](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xkh5iF).

For class types, Java is using pointers, so can you:

```
#include <memory>

class B {
 public:
  B(int);
};

bool condition();
void use(B const&);

void foo() {
  std::unique_ptr<B> b{nullptr};
  if (condition())
    b = std::make_unique<B>(42);
  else
    return;

  use(*b);
}
```

But I think you want to know is why C++ doesn't let you leave you a variable uninitialized when it is possible statically to prove that the variable will not be used without being initialized. I can't clearly answer the "why", you should probably ask that from someone on isocpp committee. That's a feature newer languages like Kotlin enjoy but C++ hasn't caught up with yet. Herb Sutter has mentioned it in a talk I know of:

You can find that talk [here](https://youtu.be/qx22oxlQmKc?t=2705):

> ... what if you could simply declare and then initialize before and make sure your first use is an initialization but they don't have to be in the same line. Well, we have the same tools; we can say what the definite first use is in every path and require initialization there before the variable's used ...

Then he goes on to talk about how we can introduce that into C++ type-system if memory serves me right, but considering this talk is from 2020, even in the best-case scenario, that feature will not be in C++ for the foreseeable future.

---

You can also have a look into "immediately invoked lambda expressions" as they could help here and they can also help you make your code more const-correct.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, semantics in Java and C++ are quite different.

In Java each local variable must go through mandatory declaration -> first assignment sequence before being read where first assignment performs initialization. There is no special concept or syntax for initialization. Writing `int x = 0;` is equivalent to `int x; x = 0;`.

In C++ things are completely different. There is no special concept or syntax for declaring local variables. There is no way to postpone initialization. But there are many different special syntaxes for initialization. `int x = 0;` is copy initialization syntax, not just declaration with first assignment on the same line. There is also so called *vacuous initialization* which happens in case of `int x;` - even though initialization is there it does not actually initialize value with anything.

But what is more important is that language capabilities in Java and C++ are quite different as well.

In Java there is no support for pass-by-reference or pass-by-pointer. There is no way to share local variable in between threads. Changes to local variable are always observable by compiler and figuring out whether it is being read without prior assignment requires only relatively straightforward control flow analysis of current scope.

In C++ there is support for both pass-by-reference and pass-by-pointer. Local variables can be accessed from different threads. But there is even more than that, local variables can be modified by means completely unknown to compiler. That's what happens when one deals with DMA (Direct Memory Access) capable devices all the time. So [there is no way for analysis to be smart enough to cover all these cases.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKuXA.png)