# How can I conditionally instantiate an object?

Tags: c++, class, optimization, conditional-statements, instantiation

I'm trying to do some conditional work like so:

```
Type object;
if (cond) {
    doSomeStuff();
    object = getObject();
    doMoreStuff();
} else {
    doSomeOtherStuff();
    object = getDifferentObject();
    doEvenMoreStuff();
}
use(object);
```

The only way I can think of solving this is the duplicate the `use` code (which is actually inline code in my application) and declare `object` in each branch of the `if` block. If I wanted to avoid duplicate code I'd have to wrap it in some use function, as I have above. In a real situation, this `use` function will probably take 5+ parameters to essentially carry over the context. This all seems messy, and impossible to maintain.

```
if (cond) {
    doSomeStuff();
    Type object = getObject();
    doMoreStuff();
    use(object);
} else {
    doSomeOtherStuff();
    Type object = getDifferentObject();
    doEvenMoreStuff();
    use(object);
}
```

What's the best approach to tackling this? `Type` has no default constructor, thus snippet 1 doesn't compile.

Some other languages support snippet 1 - Related question: [Forcing uninitialised declaration of member with a default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354194/forcing-uninitialised-declaration-of-member-with-a-default-constructor)

Comment: whats the relevance of `doSomeStuff()` and `doSomeOtherStuff()` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 its code I've abstracted.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346477/create-objects-in-conditional-c-statements

Comment: there is (almost) no duplicate code in the second version, whats wrong with taht?

Comment: @NathanOliver `Type has no default constructor, thus snippet 1 doesn't compile.`

Comment: @NathanOliver The accepted answer there given is explicitly said to not work here, and what's probably the "best" answer (a lambda) isn't even there.

Comment: `auto fn = [](bool cond) { if (cond) { doSomeStuff(); return getObject(); } doSomeOtherStuff(); return getDifferentObject(); };` and `Type object = fn(cond);`

Comment: @idclev463035818 `In a real situation, this use function will probably take 5+ parameters to essentially carry over the context. This all seems messy, and impossible to maintain.`

Comment: `std::optional`

Comment: @MooingDuck I dont want to use the HEAP - plus that's a hack

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi There is more than once answer there, the third one shows how you can do it without a default constrcutor.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi: `std::optional` does not use the heap.  Also, the normal thing to do would be to extract the if-else to a method, and return it from a function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an IIILE (immediately invoked initializing lambda expression):

```
auto object = [&] {
  if (cond) {
    doSomeStuff();
    auto object = getObject();
    doMoreStuff();
    return object;
  } else {
    doSomeOtherStuff();
    auto object = getDifferentObject();
    doEvenMoreStuff();
    return object;
  }
}();  // note that the lambda must be called

use(object);
```

This will work even if `Type` is not default-constructible.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/efv2a5).

Comment: Assuming NVRO, no move constructor should be called by the `return`s, but one is still required to exist. In order to avoid that, (only to be done if necessary: i.e. `Type` is unmovable), `return` the initializing prvalue *directly* from the lambda, and then handle the "after" code separately.

Comment: @HTNW I'm not sure I follow. With NRVO, isn't this sufficient?

Comment: @HTNW This shouldn't change anything, because of guaranteed copy elision. You'll get one move if the compiler fails to do NRVO, but there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: So, `auto` isn't necessary?

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi I'm not sure which one you're talking about, but yes, none of the `auto` in this snippet are necessary.

Comment: I meant the top one `auto object`, HTNW was speaking about how it would cause an unnecessary copy - I didn't really get any of that

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi Don't worry about that. The issue we were referring to is whether to have `auto` or `auto&&`. It's the same difference between `Type` or `Type&&`. Just use the version in the solution with `auto`/`Type`.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi You can write `Type` instead of `auto` in all three places, but it wouldn't change the amount of copies you get. This approach *may* give you one extra move (not copy) if your compiler is not smart enough (to do NRVO), otherwise you'll get no moves. The `object` won't be copied in either case.

Answer (score 6):

Put it inside a function:

```
Type doStuffAndCreateType() {
    doSomeStuff();
    Type object = getObject();
    doMoreStuff();
    return object;
}

Type doOtherStuffAndCreateType() {
    doSomeOtherStuff();
    Type object = getObject();
    doEvenMoreStuff();
    return object;
}

Type object = cond ? doStuffAndCreateType() : doOtherStuffAndCreateType();
use( object );
```

Comment: Or: `Type object = cond ? doStuffAndCreateType() : doOtherStuffAndCreateType();` No need for a 3rd function.

Comment: @RemyLebeau agreed

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at `std::optional`:

```
#include <optional>

std::optional<Type> object;
if (cond) {
    doSomeStuff();
    object = getObject();
    doMoreStuff();
} else {
    doSomeOtherStuff();
    object = getDifferentObject();
    doEvenMoreStuff();
}
use(object.value());
```

Comment: I say this as I'm actually using shared system memory, and using "placement new" so this really isn't usable - or desirable

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi: This doesn't do any heap allocations.  `std::optional` uses placement new internally.  If you're doing placement new manually already, then... just do that